# Compare data table object to date time variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to compare the current date/time to a date time located in the first row of a data table filled from an SQL query.

```
$datatable | Out-Host
```

Shows this:

```
LastRunDate
————————-
3/28/2019 1:22:01 PM
```

I need to compare that one cell to the current date and time to see when the last time the data source was updated.  I just can't figure out how to extract that cell and convert it to a date time variable.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. [SO] isn't a free script writing service. Own research and code attempts are expected. [Edit] the question to include **your** code in a [mcve]. To get the time between now and LastRunDate in seconds, simply do `([datetime]::now - [datetime]$datatable.LastRunDate).Totalseconds`

Comment: Hey!  Thank you so much, that worked perfectly.  Thanks for also telling me about the website.  As a new user, I appreciate the direction!!!

Answer (score 0):

As for...

> I just can't figure out how to extract that cell

DB or note getting to data inside an object is PowerShell into level thing. Just dot or select the variable to get only the value.

```
$debatable | Select $PSItem.LastRunDate
```

or

```
$debatable.LastRunDate
```

This is all covered in the [help files on PowerShell variables.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_variables?view=powershell-6)

```
Variables are very useful for storing the results of commands.
For example:
PowerShell

Copy
PS> $processes = Get-Process

PS> $Today = (Get-Date).date
```

As for ...

> and convert it to a date time variable.

… what you show stored is already datetime formatted. So, what are you trying to convert?
What did you search for. [DateTime manipulation](http://techgenix.com/dates-in-powershell/) is a very common PowerShell use case.

As for doin this with SQL, see the walk through..

[Working with SQL databases using PowerShell](https://virtuallysober.com/2017/07/10/working-with-sql-databases-using-powershell/)

As for comparing dates, again is a common thing.

[PowerShell: Comparing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097125/powershell-comparing-dates)

```
As Get-Date returns a DateTime object you are able to compare them directly. An example:
(get-date 2010-01-02) -lt (get-date 2010-01-01)
```

So, if you are new to this, that's fine, but, please spend time on YouTube, MSDN Channel9, Microsoft Virtual Academy, Microsoft Learning to take the visual approach to getting up to speed. Just search for PowerShell presentations / training.