# PowerShell DateTime Csv discrepancy

Tags: powershell, csv, datetime

I'm importing a CSV with a Date column where the format is "2023-5-29"
I'm specifying $mydate for a reference date.
Im looking to return all rows where the dates are greater than $mydate.

```
$myfiles  = Import-Csv -Path "C:\pathto\file.csv"
$mydate = ((Get-Date).adddays(-(6+(Get-Date -UFormat %u)))).date
$myfiles | Where-Object {$_.Date -gt $mydate.ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')}
```

My CSV looks like this:

[image]

When I run the final line, it returns every item in CSV.  Is this a datetime object issue?  Is it formatting?

Im out of ideas.  Any tips would help me.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: The issue is that you're comparing strings thinking they are comparable as if they were actual datetime instances. Please add more examples of how the dates in CSV `Date` column look like

Comment: If you want to compare dates while they are strings, then you should use a format that actually allows sorting, which `MM/dd/yyyy` is definitely not. You could use ISO format `yyyy-MM-dd`, but as your input may look like `yyyy-M-dd` (single digit month) that's also not good for sorting. Best way would be to compare date objects instead of strings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PowerShell: Comparing dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097125/powershell-comparing-dates)

Comment: The is no reason to format the compare date.  You should not be comparing strings. Should be : $mydate = (Get-Date).adddays(-6).date.  Then you just need to compare dates : $myfiles | Where-Object { Get-Date($_.Date) -gt $myDate}

Comment: This doesn't really make much sense, as this isn't even equal:  `'2023-5-28' -gt '05/28/2023'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert the strings in your `Date` CSV column to [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime?view=net-7.0) instances instead of converting your target date (`$mydate`) to a string.

```bash
$mydate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-13).Date
Import-Csv -Path 'C:\pathto\file.csv' |
    Where-Object {
        $parsed = [datetime]::ParseExact(
            $_.Date,
            'yyyy-M-d',
            [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)

        $parsed -gt $mydate
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

To complement [Santiago's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76599499/45375):

**tl;dr**

- Define your reference date as a `[datetime]` instance rather than as a *string*.
- *Cast* your CSV timestamp strings (`$_.Date`) to `[datetime]` for meaningful chronological comparison.

```bash
$myDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-6+(Get-Date -UFormat %u)).Date
Import-Csv -Path C:\pathto\file.csv |
  Where-Object { [datetime] $_.Date -gt $myDate }
```

This relies on the fact that `[datetime] '2023-5-29'` creates a `[datetime]` instance as intended (the string `'2023-5-29'` is properly recognized as 29 May 2023).
Read on for background information.

---

In order to **meaningfully compare / sort timestamps in chronological order**, they must be expressed:

- *Either* - **preferably**: as **[`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime)** or, even better, **[`[datetimeoffset]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTimeOffset)** instances:

  - Both types have rich support for date / time operations.
  - Note: Only `[datetimeoffset]` instances compare meaningfully with timestamps *from different time zones*.<sup>[1]</sup>
- *Or*: via a ***string format* format whose *lexical* sort order is equivalent to chronological order**, which notably requires a [format string](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) such as:

  - For dates alone:

    - `'yyyy"-"MM"-"dd'`<sup>[2]</sup>
    - e.g. `'2023-07-02'`
  - For dates and times (omit units as needed for less precise comparison):

    - `'yyyy"-"MM"-"dd"T"HH":"mm":"ss"."fffffff'`
    - e.g. `'2023-07-02T12:34:01.2936200'`
  - **Note**:

    - Unlike when using `[datetimeoffset]`, this approach **fundamentally only works for timestamps *from the same time zone***; incorporating a time-zone offset (e.g., `-04:00`) would *not* result in the lexical order also reflecting the chronological order.
    - These format strings can be passed to [`Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date)'s `-Format` parameter (e.g. `Get-Date -Format 'yyyy"-"MM"-"dd'`), to the `.ToString()` methods of `[datetime]` and `[datetimeoffset]` instances (e.g. `[datetime]::Now.ToString('yyyy"-"MM"-"dd')`), or when using such instances with the [`-f`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#format-operator--f) operator (e.g. `'{0:yyyy"-"MM"-"dd}' -f [datetime]::Now`)

---

**CSV data** is inherently *untyped* and therefore **invariably *string*-typed** ([`[string]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String)) when parsed into `[pscustomobject]` instances by [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) or [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv)<sup>[3]</sup>

- **Working with *string* representations** of timestamps is **only worth considering if the CSV column values are *already* in a format where their lexical order equals their chronological order**, as described above.

  - If so, you can create a matching string representation of your reference date, once, up front, and then make do with string comparisons that therefore don't require type conversions, which provides a *performance benefit* (note the use of [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) in the `Where-Object` call):

    ```bash
    # Create the reference timestamp in the same string format as the CSV data
    $mydate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-6+(Get-Date -UFormat %u)).Date.ToString('yyyy"-"MM"-"dd')
    # Filter using *string* comparison
    # Note: Works ONLY with Date column values whose lexical order
    #       ordering is equal to its chronological ordering, which does
    #       NOT apply to your data.
    $myfiles | Where-Object Date -gt $mydate
    ```
  - However, unless performance is crucial, it's still worth considering using `[datetime]` conversions, especially if you also want to store the resulting instances for additional date/time operations later - see next point.
- **Otherwise, parse the column values (timestamp strings) into `[datetime]` instances**:

  - Santiago's answer shows you how to to parse the timestamp strings *explicitly*, using a description of their format, via [`[datetime]::ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ParseExact)
  - However, **PowerShell's `[datetime]` *casts*** (which under the hood translate to [`[datetime]::Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime.ParseExact) with the [*invariant culture*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) as the cultural context) have **built-in, culture-invariant support for various formats**, including your specific format; that is, something like `[datetime] '2023-5-29'` works as-is, and is properly recognized as 29 May 2023, irrespective of what the *current* culture is (as reflected in `$PSCulture`). See the solution at the top.

---

<sup>[1] `[datetimeoffset]` instances are unambiguous points in time that have a built-in UTC offset (as implied by a given time zone); the same point in time can be expressed with different UTC offsets, and `[datetimeoffset]` recognizes this equivalence - unlike `[datetime]`, whose instances are either unspecified with respect to a UTC offset (a `.Kind` property value of `Unspecified`), represent a *local* timestamp (`Local`), or are expressed in UTC (`Utc`). Only the last kind is unambiguous, and even conceptually equivalent instances do *not* compare as equal if they are of kind `Utc` and `Local`, respectively (but equivalent `Local` and `Unspecified` ones do).</sup>

<sup>[2] Note the use of embedded quoting (`"..."`) around characters such as `-`, `:`, `.`, and `T`. This ensures their *verbatim* use during formatting; except for `T`, these characters, when used unquoted, are *placeholders* for culture-appropriate separators. However, you could get away *without* the embedded quoting if you explicitly specified `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture` as the culture context.</sup>

<sup>[3] There are two pending feature requests on GitHub for adding type support: [GitHub issue #11942](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11942) proposes allowing specifying property types via a new `-ColumnType` parameter for `Import-Csv` / `ConvertTo-Csv`. [GitHub issue #8862](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8862) proposes allowing specifying a .NET target type / custom PowerShell `class` (with strongly typed properties) with `Import-Csv` / `ConvertTo-Csv`</sup>